# pureconfig Enumeratum nicer exceptions

Tags: scala, pureconfig, enumeratum

How can I get nicer exceptions when using pureconfig with Enumeratum?
https://github.com/pureconfig/pureconfig/tree/master/modules/enumeratum

```
import pureconfig._
import pureconfig.generic.auto._
import pureconfig.module.enumeratum._
import com.typesafe.config.ConfigFactory.parseString
import enumeratum._
import enumeratum.EnumEntry._

object example {
  sealed trait Greeting extends EnumEntry with Snakecase

  object Greeting extends Enum[Greeting] {
    val values = findValues
    case object Hello extends Greeting
    case object GoodBye extends Greeting
    case object ShoutGoodBye extends Greeting with Uppercase
  }
}
import example._
case class GreetingConf(start: Greeting, end: Greeting)

val conf = parseString("""{
  start: hello
  end: SHOUT_GOOD_BYE
}""")
loadConfig[GreetingConf](conf)
```

But:

```
val conf = parseString("""{
      start: helloError
      end: SHOUT_GOOD_BYEFoo
    }""")
    loadConfig[GreetingConf](conf)
```

Fails with a nasty exception. Instead a descriptive Message similar to:

```
Can't parse key start to ENUM type Greeting. Only [hello, SHOUT_GOOD_BYE] are valid values.
```

would be great.
How can I achieve this?

Comment: `val conf = parseString("""{
         start: hello
      end: SHOUT_GOOD_BYE
    }""")
    loadConfig[GreetingConf](conf)`

should work